# How to get the original value when update entity property?

Tags: entity-framework

When update/modify entity property, I can put business logic in property changed event like:

```
partial void OnMyPropertyChanged()
{
  //....
}
```

In this event handler, I want to know the new value and original value for MyProperty. 
New value can be get by this.MyProperty. How to get the original value?

For example, if udpate MyProperty from 1 to 2, original value is 1, new value is 2. 
this.MyProperty = 2. but how to get the original value 1?

Answer (score 0):

In EF2 the Entities are also implementing `INotifyPropertyChanging`. I don't know if it's the same in EF4. 
You should be able to listen to the `PropertyChanging` event and so read the value of the property before it is changed.